# Issue with implementing a grid

Tags: html, css, shopify, grid-layout

Within an shopify homepage image grid I'd like to overlay a number of things on top of each image: e.g. on top of the blue shirt 2 text divs (TEXTLINE 1 and TEXTLINE 2)and 1 image. When I add the text lines everything looks as it should:

[image: how the grid should look like]

But, when I include the image (white flower) the parent image is enlarged. TEXTLINE 2 hast the markup cta-text and the image cta-image
[image]

This is my CSS:

```css
.tile-group {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  .tile { display: none; }
  .tile.loaded {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;    
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  a {
    display: block;
    @include vendor-prefix(transition, opacity 300ms);
    &:hover {
      opacity: $image-hover-opacity;
    }
  }

  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    &:before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: -5px;
    }
    .inner {
      @extend h4;
      color: $home-tile-text-col;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: auto;
      padding: 20px 25px;
      @if $home-tile-text-bg-col != transparent and $home-tile-text-bg-col != rgba(0,0,0,0) {
        background: rgba($home-tile-text-bg-col, $home-tile-text-bg-transparency);
      }
      .cta-text{
        width: 30%;
        position: absolute;
        font-size:24px;
        left:35%;
        bottom: 5%;
        text-transform: uppercase; 
      }
      .cta-image{
        width: 30%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 35%;
        bottom: 10%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  {% if settings[url_idx] != empty %}<a href="{{ settings[url_idx] | escape }}">{% endif %}
  <img src="{% comment %}ly_asset_replace_for_[ filename | asset_url ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% assign ly_asset = filename %}{% include 'ly-asset' with ly_asset %}{{ ly_translation  }}{% comment %}ly_asset_replace_end{% endcomment %}" alt="{{ settings[alt_idx] | escape }}" />
  {% if settings[overlay_idx] != blank %}
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="inner">
       {{ settings[overlay_idx] }}
  <div class="cta-image">
        {{ "lotos.png" | asset_url | img_tag:"CTA Image" }}
  </div>
       <div class="cta-text">
        {{ settings[cta_text] }}
     </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if settings[url_idx] != empty %}</a>{% endif %}
</div>

{% endcapture %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}


<section class="border-top section tile-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tile-group">
      {{ img_tiles_html }}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Outputted HTML is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5wvL8MtrjCHX0VNdWRTME1LcXc)

How can I get the grid behave as in screenshot 1?

Comment: post it with your html code ..

Comment: your outputted/compiled HTML code, please.